# LINQ to SQL - Join, Group, and Sum

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following SQL that works as expected:

```
SELECT  p.ACCT_ID AS [Acct], 
    a.ACCT_NAME AS [AcctName], 
    p.PD_NO AS [Period], 
    p.FY_CD AS [FY], 
    SUM(CUR_AMT) AS [CActual], 
    SUM(CUR_BUD_AMT) AS [CBudget], 
    SUM(YTD_AMT) AS [YActual], 
    SUM(YTD_BUD_AMT) as [YBudget] 
FROM BudgetTotals p 
INNER JOIN BudgetAccounts a 
    ON p.ACCT_ID = a.ACCT_ID WHERE p.ACCT_ID IN ('610','620','630','634','641','642','643','644','646','665','620','DFC','DFR','DGN','DTX') 
    AND FY_CD == "2013" 
    AND PD_NO == 12 
    AND POOL_NO == 23 
GROUP BY p.ACCT_ID, a.ACCT_NAME, p.PD_NO, p.FY_CD;
```

I'm trying to convert the above to Linq to Sql with the following:

```
var query = from p in db.POOL_SIE_SUPPORTs
            join c in db.ACCTs on p.ACCT_ID equals c.ACCT_ID
            where arr.Contains(p.ACCT_ID) && p.POOL_NO == 23 && p.FY_CD == "2013" && p.PD_NO == 12
            group p by p.ACCT_ID into s
            select new
            {
                Account = s.Key,
                AccountName = from acct in db.ACCTs select new { acct.ACCT_NAME },
                CTDActual = string.Format("{0:C}", s.Sum(y => y.CUR_AMT)),
                CTDBudget = string.Format("{0:C}", s.Sum(y => y.CUR_BUD_AMT)),
                YTDActual = string.Format("{0:C}", s.Sum(y => y.YTD_AMT)),
                YTDBudget = string.Format("{0:C}", s.Sum(y => y.YTD_BUD_AMT))
           };
```

How can I get my query to return the column `AccountName`?

Comment: arent you already doing that?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The column AccountName doesn't appear on the gridview when binding to the query.

Comment: but you are selecting it in your query, it might be better to show us your gridview code?

Comment: Problem is the query here I believe, because AccountName is being assigned a list instead of a single item.

Comment: You need to use s.Key(the Acct_id), to select only the single name you want for AccountName.  Probably need a .Single() but I don't remember how to do that in linq syntax as I usually use extension methods.  Hopefully someone can demonstrate that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This assumes there is only one Acct_Name per given Acct_Id, otherwise you'll get multiple records just like when you do a group by:

```
var query = from p in db.POOL_SIE_SUPPORTs
            join c in db.ACCTs on p.ACCT_ID equals c.ACCT_ID
            where arr.Contains(p.ACCT_ID) && p.POOL_NO == 23 && p.FY_CD == "2013" && p.PD_NO == 12
            group p by new { p.ACCT_ID, p.ACCT_NAME } into s
            select new
            {
                Account = s.Key.ACCT_ID,
                AccountName = s.Key.ACCT_NAME, 
                CTDActual = string.Format("{0:C}", s.Sum(y => y.CUR_AMT)),
                CTDBudget = string.Format("{0:C}", s.Sum(y => y.CUR_BUD_AMT)),
                YTDActual = string.Format("{0:C}", s.Sum(y => y.YTD_AMT)),
                YTDBudget = string.Format("{0:C}", s.Sum(y => y.YTD_BUD_AMT))
           };
```

Comment: Outstanding Aaron! The second option did it. Thank you so much.